# A plane travelling into the past

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, anthology-book

This is the story about a plane, which on its journey enters into the past. It cannot land anywhere. It opens with the real life incident of a plane which was lost forever without a trace and nobody wants to talk about it.

If you read the story you will feel that the author must be a professional pilot. The story has a graphic description of the cockpit, operations in the cockpit, etc. They identify the destination by the various landmarks only to realize it is full of jungles instead of skyscrapers! Another place they find that the year is something 1930. The fuel gauge is going down and down...

Please help me to identify the story and the anthology in which it was included.

Comment: This question is very terse. You've said that you remember the story clearly. Can you give some more detail?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @14111 It is a proper commercial airliner in 1980s

Comment: There was a Twilight Zone (original 1960s series) episode like this, with a Boeing 707 (which were pretty up-to-date when the original series first aired).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be an episode of the original *Twilight Zone* -- ["The Odyssey of Flight 33"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Odyssey_of_Flight_33) aired February 24, 1961.  All of these episodes were published in short story collections, under the pseudonym of Rod Serling (who as far as I know was involved in writing the scripts for the show, but did not himself rewrite those into story form for publication), and per comments, this specific one was also published (many years later) as a [graphic novel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439598568).

A commercial airliner (a Boeing 707) slips through a time barrier (internally hypothesized to be due to entering "a freak jet stream") and finds itself in the past.  The deep past, with dinosaurs and jungle and no long, flat, paved landing strips, then the 1930s, where there would be no compatible control radios or navigation systems (never mind jet fuel) and the runways at La Guardia are too short for a 707 -- and running low on fuel, they ascend once more to the altitude and heading that took them through time before -- and there the episode ends.

Comment: Note that there was a graphic novel made of this episode https://www.amazon.com/Odyssey-Flight-Serlings-Twilight-Zone/dp/1439598568.

Comment: Also, the cockpit dialogue was extremely realistic (quoting from http://www.self.gutenberg.org/articles/eng/the_odyssey_of_flight_33): Serling’s brother, aviation writer Robert J. Serling, helped Serling with the cockpit dialogue for the show by discussing show’s premise with a Trans World Airlines captain; after the show aired, several pilots later wrote to say that they thought the cockpit dialogue was among the most authentic ever in a television show (albeit the situation described was impossible).

Comment: THANKS. Thanks a lot. This is the story !!  It is in  "The twilight zone "" Complete Stories by  Rod Serling.