# Book (CYOA?) involving the ghost of a pilot who manifests as a face in a microwave

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

I was reminded of this one when reading [A plane travelling into the past](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250942/a-plane-travelling-into-the-past). I'm 90% certain this may have been a CYOA, or one of its knockoffs, maybe involving paranormal research given the bit I'm remembering. Said scene involves the ghost of a pilot involved in a prior crash manifesting on a plane the antagonist is on and, for whatever reason, he manifests as a face in the microwave. I can still largely recall the drawing (which I may try replicating later today if I get no bites on the description alone) where he then tells the protagonist about a mechanical issue with the plane, which allows them to land safely.

That illustration is hanging in the front of my head, black and white pen drawing, showing a floating head in a microwave, I believer no pupils and no neck, mouth partly open in speech.

Comment: This is ringing a bell with me as well.....!  Could of been a stewardess that sees the face in the microwave window

Comment: I think I'm recalling seeing a summary of a tragic plane crash and the investigation of the paranormal sightings that followed...https://www.amazon.com/Ghost-Flight-401-John-Fuller/dp/0425062341

Comment: @Alith Huh... they do have a similar scenario as per https://www.ozy.com/true-and-stories/flying-the-ghostly-skies/232247/, "Flight attendants claimed to have seen Repo’s reflection in an oven door in the galley."

Comment: And indeed, reading some excerpts from the book, as found on archive.org, this does sound either I had a particular illustration of *The Ghosts of Flight 401* in mind, or maybe a reference in another book about the paranormal.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots OP's question made me think of the TV movie ["The Ghost of Flight 401"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077610/), which was based on a book of the same name which was based on [true events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Air_Lines_Flight_401) and the purported ghost sightings that ensued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if this might be [Poltergeists, Ghosts and Psychic Encounters](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8542596-poltergeists-ghosts-and-psychic-encounters). It's a gamebook from the series ["Which Way Books"](https://gamebooks.org/Series/29/Show).

[image: Front cover]

The back cover (sorry the image is so large) mentions a similar haunting - "the plane with a long dead captain". And [a review on Demian's Gamebook Web Page](https://gamebooks.org/Item/3591/Show) states "The ghost story had a few varieties... the dead pilot haunting the plane was intense..."

[image: Back cover]

Note that the main character is visiting *"a private eye of the supernatural"* - fitting in with the paranormal research theme you mention. And [this webpage](https://horrordelve.com/2014/04/05/horror-themed-adventure-game-books/) states:

> While visiting your uncle, a supernatural investigator, you can become involved in several paranormal investigations. There’s a house with a poltergeist, a phantom wedding, and more.

Here's a scan of one of the internal pages, showing the protagonist and uncle involved in some paranormal investigation:

[image]

Going by [the series page on Demian's Gamebooks](https://gamebooks.org/Series/29/Show), this series was the successor to a series that was itself a predecessor to *Choose Your Own Adventure*. It is described as:

> a collection of simple branching-plot books. The books cover a variety of genres and are distinguished mainly by their often very brief text passages between choices.

So it sounds as though it *might* be a little closer to a traditional book than the gamebook format we've become familiar with. That might fit in with you only being 90% sure that it's a CYOA.

Comment: If this turns out to be the correct book, I found it by googling *pilot ghost gamebook*

Comment: I've put out an ILL request to verify it, but that cover does look familiar.

Comment: It's currently for sale on ABE (https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=31002324120) - $1.45 plus $3.99 shipping. I'm not sure if these "for sale" links are typically frowned on in SE comments, but the ILL request you made doesn't seem to be getting anywhere.

Comment: The author also has her own website - http://www.nancylamb.com/ - *"I published 26 Which Way Books with a partner under the name of R.G. Austin"*. You might be able to contact her via that and ask if she still has a copy of the book and can scan the relevant page.

Comment: I have a copy coming. I'll accept for now. Thank you.